# Attribute added with setattr not showing up in help()

Tags: python, reflection

I've got a class that I'm adding a help-function to with setattr. The function is a properly created instancemethod and works like a charm.

```
import new
def add_helpfunc(obj):
    def helpfunc(self):
        """Nice readable docstring"""
        #code

    setattr(obj, "helpfunc", 
            new.instancemethod(helpfunc, obj, type(obj)))
```

However, when calling help on the object instance, the new method is not listed as a member of the object. I thought help (i.e. pydoc) used dir(), but dir() works and not help().

What do I have to do to get the help information updated?

Comment: What is the benefit gained from doing this? I don't mean to sound skeptical, I'm honestly curious.

Comment: The use-case for this sort of adding-in-functions is that we have a set of classes that we want to use in one way as developers, but use in a more wrapped-up-and-pretty way in an interactive shell. Rather than have parallel class hierarchies or some such, we inject a bit of good-to-haves into the existing classes and remove some too-powerful functions to make the shell more friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I there a specific reason you do it the complicate way? Why not just doing it like this:

```
def add_helpfunc(obj):
    def helpfunc(self):
        """Nice readable docstring"""
        #code

    obj.helpfunc = helpfunc
```

Adding the method this way also fixes your help-problem if I am not wrong...

Example:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> add_helpfunc(A)
>>> help(A.helpfunc)
Help on method helpfunc in module __main__:

helpfunc(self) unbound __main__.A method
    Nice readable docstring

>>> help(A().helpfunc)
Help on method helpfunc in module __main__:

helpfunc(self) method of __main__.A instance
    Nice readable docstring
```

Comment: This does seem to work the same as the above solution, so it's better in that regard. It does however exhibit the same failure with help. But I think the issue really is that the function is being added on the OBJECT, but help is for the CLASS. unfortunately I don't want to add it to every instance, just a particular subset. Maybe it's just a class missing in the hierarchy, screaming to be created...

Comment: I'm not sure you're right. See my update (You have to call the add_helpfunc on the class, not on the instance)

Comment: And adding it to the class means that the information will be displayed for every instance of the class. Basically if I have a=A() and b=A() then I want to be able to add_helpfunc(b) and get different results from help(a) and help(b). I think that your answer is the only actual solution and I just need to create a new class so that help gets different classes or live with the help info not being complete.